Acid Rain Killing Woman
I saw this movie/series at least 10 years ago. 
I think this was the beginning, and it shows a caucasian woman in a village surrounded by forest. It starts raining, everyone goes inside, and in the next scene, the woman is dead. The rain was acidic (?) and the woman's eyes have melted. I seem to remember yellow in her face, might be because she's blonde or the eyes melted to yellow.
The scene showing her dead body is shot from above, and she's lying on the ground with her eyes facing up. I also think a scream is heard, or someone crying.

Other than the X Files, I'm blanking out, sorry. And I'm afraid all I could find online was just another person who might be looking for the same movie. Maybe their (slightly different) description would help.

The movie in the other page seems to be The Return of the Living Dead, but I feel BlueMoon93 would mention zombies if they were in his movie.

Try the opening scene of the X files episode El Mundo Gira (season 4, episode 11).

Agents Fox Mulder and Dana Scully investigate the death of Maria Dorantes, an illegal immigrant from Mexico living in the San Joaquin Valley near Fresno, California who was found dead, with her face partially eaten away, after yellow rain fell from the sky. Maria was the object of the love of two brothers, Eladio and Soledad Buente; Soledad blames his brother for her death. The migrants believe that the so-called "Chupacabra" was responsible for her death, despite the fact that none of the circumstances of the death resemble anything close to reports of the Chupacabra. Mulder, assisted on the case by Mexican-American INS agent Conrad Lozano, is able to track down and interrogate Eladio, who frightens the other migrants. Meanwhile, Scully discovers that Maria was killed by a fungal growth known as Aspergillus.
Eladio escapes as he is being deported, killing a truck driver in the process. A clinical exam on the driver shows his death was caused by a rapid growth of Trichophyton — the Athlete's foot fungus. Scully brings samples of the fatal fungi to a mycologist who discovers that their abnormally rapid growth was caused by an unidentifiable enzyme. This revelation leads Scully to suspect Eladio of being an unwitting carrier of the enzyme, necessitating his immediate capture. Eladio, seeking to return to Mexico, meets with his cousin Gabrielle to ask for money. He works with a construction foreman for the day to make the money. Soledad comes after him, seeking to kill him, but finds the foreman dead. Eladio escapes in the foreman's truck and heads to the grocery store where Gabrielle works, spreading the fungal growth. The agents later confront Soledad at the supermarket, discovering another dead victim of the fungus.
Eladio returns to see Gabrielle, but by now has grown deformed from the fungus. Gabrielle, afraid of him, gives him her money and lies to the agents about his location when they come to see her. In actuality, Eladio has returned to the camp where Maria died, where Lozano tries to spur Soledad on in killing his brother. Soledad finds he can't do it, and Lozano struggles with him, being accidentally killed when the gun goes off. Soledad becomes a carrier of the fungal growth himself and flees with Eladio towards Mexico.


It's actually quite close, but it's not the scene I remember. I remember a town with a lot more green than this (this one is too muddy). Good guess tho

Even though its not the same, have the bounty for your trouble =)
